# MongoCollection::aggregate() is undefined in Heroku PHP using MongoHQ

Tags: php, mongodb, heroku, php-mongodb, mongohq

I'm getting the following error when using MongoDB's `aggregate()` function in a PHP code. This code perfectly works on my local setup which is running MongoDB 2.2.3

```
PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined method MongoCollection::aggregate() in /app/www/page.php on line 52, referer: http://referrer.url
```

**Code**

```
foreach($cats as $key=>$val){
    $cats2[$val['lable']] = $myCollection->aggregate( array(
                                array('$match' => array('user_id' => $user_id )),
                                array('$unwind' =>"\$data"),
                                array('$match' => array('data.category'=> $val['category'])),
                                array('$project' => array('name'=> "\$data.name", 'id'=>"\$data.id")),
                                array('$group' => array('_id'=>'$id', 'name'=> array('$first' =>'$name'))),
                                array('$limit' => 12)
                                    ));
}
```

**Environment**

- PHP on Heroku
- MongoDB 2.2.4 with MongoHQ Add-on

Comment: This is normally caused by an old driver, you will want to upgrade the driver for your MongoDB installation

Comment: The aggregate method was introduced in 1.3.0. Looks like you are running 1.2.xx :]

Comment: Solved. I compiled the PHP MongoDB driver by my self on the Heroku environment. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to look into your `phpinfo()`

If in the version you see something less than `1.3.0`, then it will not work.

[image]

Go to [mongo driver page](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/drivers/php/) download and add appropriate driver.
Restart the server and it will work.