# Undefined method aggregateCursor() while operating with mongodb

Tags: php, mongodb

Getting forllowing error while working with `PHP` + `MongoDB`.

```
undefined method MongoCollection::aggregateCursor()

[ $aggregate = array(array('$group' => array('_id' => '$player_id','player_total_score' => array('$sum' => '$total_score'))));

$result = $collection->aggregateCursor($aggregate);]
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16073893/mongocollectionaggregate-is-undefined-in-heroku-php-using-mongohq

Comment: Can you show us the relevant piece of code?

Comment: Mongodb version support is  "1.4.5 " [means above 1.3.0]